# CDN not working parallel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datetime, cdn

I'm using this CDN

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
```

and in parallel two others cdn

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If one is working and another not working how can I implement these two or more cdn.

Comment: Uhm, it is not clear to me what you are trying to ask. Please try to review your question as a different person and see if you can understand it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Answer (score 0):

Above both paths are for jquery library so You can not insert jquery library twice in single page, otherwise it will not work.

Include jquery library only once.